# Clearing Open Zeppelin Enumerable Map

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin

Supposed I have an enumerable map, now I want to clear it so it doesn't contain any element. What is the most gas efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `EnumerableMap` uses struct `Set` to store the data. To reset a struct, you can use the keyword `delete` to clear all the slots.

```
function clearSet(Set storage set) public {
    delete set;
}
```

Comment: That works, thanks!

Comment: You are very welcome!